# How to expire a link after three days in UTC?

Tags: python-2.7

I have this issue and I need a solution real quick. For forget password I will send a link to the user email provided and then I have to store the expire time of that link in riak along with some data. Now I need to store that(expired) time in UTC.

```
import time
created = time.mktime(time.gmtime())
>>> created = 1390218621.0
```

this will gives me the time from epoch.

Now I need to store expire time lets say the link should expire after three days I need the epoch time after three days for UTC so that I will check the expired with the current Epoch in UTC and then do the validations. Can u please tell me how to calculate the expired time.

Answer (score 0):

There are 86,400 seconds in a day.  Epoch time as you have calculated it is in seconds.

```
created + ( 3 * 86400 );
```